using dxFIleManager from devExtreme to upload files in chuck
I have configured dxFileManager like this (check the uploadFileChunk function) :
$('#md_DocumentiServizio').dxFileManager({
            name: 'fileManager',
            fileSystemProvider: new DevExpress.fileManagement.CustomFileSystemProvider({ 
            getItems: function(pathInfo) { 
              return $.ajax({
                        url: "./include/gestione_servizio/documenti/getDocumenti.php",
                        method: "GET",
                        data: {
                          Lingua: lingua_attiva,
                                  IdSped: dati_testata.trkbid,
                                  selPath: pathInfo.path
                        },
                        dataType: "json"
                    })
                    
            },
            downloadItems: function(items) {                
                items.forEach(function (item, index) {
                    

                const jsonData = JSON.stringify(item);
                    
                              $.ajax({
                        url: "./include/gestione_servizio/documenti/saveDocumenti.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: jsonData,
                        xhrFields: {
                          responseType: "blob"
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                        const filename = item.name;
                        const file = new File([data], filename, {type: data.type});
                        saveAs(file);
                        }
                    });
                    
                            });
                },              
            uploadFileChunk: function(fileData, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory) {             
                

                console.log(uploadInfo);

                
                const formData = new FormData();
                          formData.append('file', fileData);
                          formData.append('uploadInfo', JSON.stringify(uploadInfo));
                          formData.append('destinationDirectory', JSON.stringify(destinationDirectory));


                        return $.ajax({
                        url: "./include/gestione_servizio/documenti/uploadDocumenti.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: formData,
                              processData: false,
                              contentType: false
                        });

                }
        }),
            height: 450,
            permissions: {
              create: false,
              copy: false,
              move: false,
              delete: true,
              rename: false,
              upload: true,
              download: true
            }
        });

and the upload file in PHP is configured like this:
<?php
$temp_files_location = "c:/temp/temp/";

try {


    if (!isset($_FILES['file']) || !isset($_POST['uploadInfo']) || !isset($_POST['destinationDirectory'])) {
        throw new Exception('Dati mancanti (file, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory)');
    }


    $uploadInfo = json_decode($_POST['uploadInfo'], true); // Assicurati di ottenere un array associativo
    $destinationDirectory = json_decode($_POST['destinationDirectory'], true); // Assicurati di ottenere un array associativo

    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new Exception('Dati JSON non validi in uploadInfo o destinationDirectory');
    }

    if (!file_exists($temp_files_location)) {
        if (!mkdir($temp_files_location, 0755, true)) {
            throw new Exception('Impossibile creare la cartella temporanea: ' . $temp_files_location);
        }
    }


    $temp_file_path = tempnam($temp_files_location, 'chunk_');


    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $temp_file_path)) {
        throw new Exception('Impossibile spostare il chunk caricato');
    }


    if ($uploadInfo['chunkIndex'] === $uploadInfo['chunkCount'] - 1) {
        if (filesize($temp_file_path) > 1024 * 400000) {
            throw new Exception('File troppo grande');
        }

       
    }
    

if ($uploadInfo['chunkIndex'] === $uploadInfo['chunkCount'] - 1) {
    $target_location = $destinationDirectory['dataItem']['basePath'] . $destinationDirectory['key'] . '/';


    $target_file_path = $target_location . $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $target_file = fopen($target_file_path, 'a+');
    if (!$target_file) {
        throw new Exception('Impossibile aprire il file di destinazione per la scrittura');
    }

    $chunk_data = file_get_contents($temp_file_path); // Leggi i dati del chunk
    fwrite($target_file, $chunk_data); // Aggiungi il chunk al file di destinazione
    fclose($target_file); // Chiudi il file di destinazione


    unlink($temp_file_path);
}

} catch (Exception $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    exit;
}

Upload seems to work correctly, however I don't understand two things:

why if I upload a file of 3.5Mb I find in the temp folder about 17 files of the same size as the original?

Why at the end the files in the temp folder do not delete?


What am I doing wrong?

I solved the problem. I had to send to PHP the chunk of the file from JavaScript, not the full file.
